# How do I make multiple requests while preserving the session with restsharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

First I have to get the csrf value by sending a GET request.
I need to post json content to a different url while preserving session information (cookies, headers, etc.).

```
            var client = new RestClient("https://example.com");
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2225.0 Safari/537.36");

            var response1 = client.Execute(request);
            if (response1.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string source1 = Uri.UnescapeDataString(response1.Content);
                string address1 = response1.ResponseUri.ToString();

                string csrfstate = Parse(source1, "RpsCsrfState%3d", "&");
                
                //POST 

                //client = new RestClient(postAdres);//2 URL
                //request = new RestRequest(postAdres, Method.Post);
                request.Method = Method.Post;
                request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

                request.AddHeader("csrf", csrfstate);
                string body = "{\"userId\":\"asd\",\"password\":\"welcome\"}";
                request.AddStringBody(body, ContentType.Json);

                var response2 = client.Execute(request);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You also add header parameters to the client, and they will be added
> to every request made by the client. This is useful for adding
> authentication headers, for example.

```
client.AddDefaultHeader(string name, string value);
```

[Docs here](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#headers)

Answer (score 0):

RestSharp never re-used anything between different requests. I am not sure what do you mean by keeping the session headers, but if you need to propagate cookies, there are two ways to do it.

One way is to use the client-level cookie container:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(baseUrl) {
    CookieContainer = myContainer
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```

Second option is to use the custom cookie container for the `HttpClientMessageHandler`.

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(baseUrl) {
    ConfigureMessageHandler = h => {           
        ((HttpClientHandler)h).CookieContainer = myContainer;
        return h;
    }
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```